# Errors using the glut library with C++/CLI

Tags: c++-cli, glut

I've been using OpenGL with glut for quite a while now and have never encountered this issue.

I've been trying to include the glut library in my c++/cli project for the use of it's library functions like glutMouseFunc etc. My project already uses gl.h and glu.h. However the moment I include:

```
#include <gl/glut.h>
```

I get the following string of error messages.

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\gl/glut.h(490): error C3641: 'glutInit_ATEXIT_HACK' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\gl/glut.h(490): error C2664: '__glutInitWithExit' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int)'
1>          Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\gl/glut.h(507): error C3641: 'glutCreateWindow_ATEXIT_HACK' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\gl/glut.h(507): error C2664: '__glutCreateWindowWithExit' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int)'
1>          Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\gl/glut.h(553): error C3641: 'glutCreateMenu_ATEXIT_HACK' : invalid calling convention '__stdcall ' for function compiled with /clr:pure or /clr:safe
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\gl/glut.h(553): error C2664: '__glutCreateMenuWithExit' : cannot convert parameter 2 from 'void (__cdecl *)(int)' to 'void (__cdecl *)(int)'
1>          Address of a function yields __clrcall calling convention in /clr:pure and /clr:safe; consider using __clrcall in target type
```

I've read in a few other places that similar problems have been solved by switching the clr support in the project's properties (properties>configuration properties>general>common language runtime  support) to anything that's not clr:safe or clr:pure.

I've in fact tried compiling with all 4 available versions of clr support:

**Common Language runtime support (/clr)**

**Pure MSIL Common Language Runtime Support (/clr:pure)**

**Safe MSIL Common Language Runtime Support (/clr:safe)**

**Common Language Runtime Support, Old Syntax (/clr:oldSyntax)**

However I still receive the same error message. I've no idea where this issue comes from. I've used glut in other projects (c++ only), and never encountered this problem until i started using c++/cli.

Any insight into what this could be would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Guy

(By the way, I'm using Visual Studio 2010 if it turns out to be of any relevance.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message you're displaying will not occur if using `/clr` to compile a file, only `/clr:pure` or `/clr:safe`.

You definitely need to use `/clr`, and not use `/clr:pure` or `/clr:safe`, as the latter flags will not allow you to use native code at all within the .cpp file.  Make sure you don't have a single file overriding the project settings for `/clr`, either, as this can cause the compiler to create errors such as you're displaying for those files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you please give an example of what you mean be "overriding the project settings". As far as I know, I haven't changed my project settings anywhere else but in Visual Studio.

Comment: @GuyJoelMcLean You can specify a `/clr` setting as a property of a *specific .cpp file* as well as for the project.  A file's properties will "override" the project settings (so a project can be `/clr`, but a specific .cpp file be set to be `/clr:pure`)

Comment: We'll this is quite eerie. I wen't through and checked my build configs (both 'debug' and 'release') for the project. If you select 'all configurations' VS2010 will make clear to you which settings differ between configs. The ONLY difference between the 2 were the 'additional dependencies', which the debug config contained the opengl32.lib, glut.lib and glu32.lib, which id forgotten to copy over to the release config. So i copied these over to the release config, and then compiled using 'release'. It now compiles fine.
You are most likely correct....

Comment: I have probably accidently switched the clr support on the debug config for a singular file. However i wouldnt have done this on the release config, as I have been working in debug until this moment. Which explains why it now works for release. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to let the compiler know that glut.h is a header for unmanaged code.  If it doesn't know then it will assume that is contains managed functions and it doesn't like what it sees.  You do so like this:

```
#pragma managed(push, off)
#include <gl/glut.h>
#pragma managed(pop)
```

A more general way to keep out of trouble like this is by strictly separating the C++/CLI code from the native code.  You can turn on the /clr option for individual source files, it doesn't need to be turned on for *every* source code file in your project.  This also helps to get native code compiled to machine code instead of IL, it is faster that way.